Office 356 Email - How to get the Authentication-Results header
I am working on an application that needs to take a Office 365 email and parse some information.
The problem is that I need a way avoid spoofing and to ensure the email actually came from a specified domain. According to my research, the best way to do that would be to check the Authentication-Results header, and check the DMARC/DKIM/SPF authentication results. This can easily be done manually if I go to my inbox, right-click the specified messages -> View -> View message details.
Is there a way for me to get this information from an outside application?
I tried getting the email through Power Automate & send to my application through an api, but Power Automate actually removes the Authentication-Results header.

MxToolbox is pretty good for checking DMARC etc. I know they have an api however not tried it out so might be worth checking that out.
